Angular 17 Nx Dynamic Module Federation Webpack ModuleFederationDevServer CORS on node modules
Access to script at 'node:module' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app.Understand this error
node_modules_wxx-platform_xx_fesm2022_xx-f2fb961.js:1
GET node:module net::ERR_FAILEDUnderstand this error
main.ts:3 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_xx-platform_xx-header_fesm2022_xx-platform-xx-header-f2fb961 failed.
Version
Angular 17
NX
ModuleFederation
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-architects/module-federation": "^18.0.4",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~17.3.0",
"@angular-devkit/core": "~17.3.0",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "~17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~17.3.0",
"@angular/cli": "^18.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.3.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~17.3.0",
"@nrwl/angular": "^19.6.4",
"@nrwl/workspace": "^19.6.2",
}
When trying to serve the page and access localhost:4200 , the node_modules loading fails with cors error.
**we tried settings CORS headers ,bu the error is given below
**
"serve": {
"executor": "@nx/angular:module-federation-dev-server",
  "options": {
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }        
      "publicHost": "http://localhost:4200" 

  }

}
